# How to monitor team members activity and effectiveness?

Tags: team-management, team

I would like to measure the effectiveness and efficiency of my team members.  I'd like the measurement to be relatively objective and transparent, and I believe that some form of software would fulfill those objectives.

How could I search for and evaluate such software?  What **kinds** of software incorporate these kinds of features
(While software recommendations are out of scope because they change frequently, the underlying requirements should be more stable.)

Is there software that might:
 - Diagram activity over the past year
 - Facilitate peer evaluation?
 - Measure improvement?

Are there non-software procedures that would assist?

Comment: [software recommendations are out of scope for PM:SE](http://pm.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Hmm, but where else should i ask ?

Comment: Not sure.  This is a frequently debated topic, but all the SE sites I participate in have similar policies. Software recommendations are simply too ephemeral to make good SE questions.

Comment: i found there is software recomandation site of SE? but it is curretnly closed beta.

Comment: But i would like to know experience of such tools from project managers and team leaders. Or just the right keyword to use in google. I am not native speaker so it is kinda a problem for me :)

Comment: It is not possible for any tool to give meaningful measurements in most knowledge type projects. It is not like building a house where it is easy to see progress. Who did more work, the guy who coded 1000 lines of bug-ridden code or the person who removed 500 of those lines and made the code work correctly and is now maintainable? Who performed better/was more important, the person stuck on a problem they had no idea how to fix or the person that pointed them in the right direction that allowed them to solve the problem? Your goal is a fool's folly. Any smart person will game the system.

Comment: If you want to evaluate people's performance just pay attention. The team members behavior towards each other and their confidence in various people will tell you all the information you need.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very generic - actually too generic to be able to give a concrete answer. It depends on what kind of project you manage and how you can measure effectiveness and efficiency of team members.

### IS/IT - Application Development Project

If you manage an Application Development project, you probably use an Agile Software Development model like Scrum and thereby use the different artifacts (documentation) on different levels.

The Scrum teams can break down backlog items in their Sprint Planning to actual tasks and can document them in for example Jira (and connect with Confluence) and thereby have some sort of follow up. (I am not an expert of Jira though, so I can't actually give you more than that.)

Another thing to consider in Application Development projects is the amount of Technical Debt, i.e. the cost of bad code, meaning bad design or just bad code convention. Even if the code compiles and run, you can end up with bugs and especially later on, when adding features you might be forced to spend a lot of time refactoring your code. A great tool for measuring Technical Debt is [SonarSource](http://www.sonarsource.com/) and [supports a number of languages today](http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/languages/).

### Product projects (e.g. Automotive industry)

If you are in the Automotive industry and manage a vehicle project, you probably manage it in a waterfall model and use different kinds of documentation for different purposes. Common to have Requirement tools, Project Management tools for planning on different levels and Project Time logging tool where coworkers are logging their time to the different projects they are involved in.

If I remember correct, I think the company I used to work for used MS Project with specific templates for the project planning, a SAP Module for Time logging and then we had some plugin which visualized the resources over time, either by department or project and could also be used to foresee any resource complications. In other words, both following up on actual spent time as well as projected in order to avoid problems ahead.

Remember, that is only time. How do you measure quality?

### With that said...

...it depends on

- what type of projects you are managing?

  - what type of Project Model you are using? (Agile/Scrum, Waterfall...)
- what type of tools you use today

  - for project planning on different levels (phases, tasks...)?
  - for time logging, and which level (project, phases, tasks)?
- What is most important of QDCF? (Quality, Delivery, Cost, Feature)

  - How do you measure Quality?
  - How do you measure Delivery?
  - How do you measure Cost?
  - How do you measure Feature? (Scope - value added for customers)
- what type of efficiency you want to measure?

  - Time efficiency only? (Project Plan vs Actual time spent)
  - Index of Time vs. Quality?
  - Time & Cost vs. Quality & Features or some other algorithm index you have for QDCF?

**NOTE!** - As you can see, project planning and time logging have to be matched "level wise", i.e. if you want to have detailed information in your efficiency reports, you need to have your coworkers log their time on a level that corresponds to same level from project planning.

So, there are a lot of questions you need to answer and define whithin your company, before you can actually decide what kind of measurement you want, and then choose/design a tool for measuring what you want. Don't forget about Quality, and the rest of QDCF.

Comment: Hi Pixic, just wanted to welcome you to PMSE. We typically mark these types of questions as off-topic since they mostly lead to spam, but since both you, and the asker, focused on process and evaluation, and since your post is very thorough, I'm going to leave it open for now. Be sure to check out our [meta] as well as our [chat], where the community discusses site goals and site issues.

Comment: Thank you @jmort253. Yes, I understand. Saw the comments on the question, even though I don't really understand why. Will check them out... Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the methodology used ([SCRUM](http://www.scrumalliance.org), [V model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V-Model) or [traditional waterfall](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/comparing-agile-project-management-and-the-traditi.html)) AND depending on the type of engagement(projects with a clear start and a clear end or on-going Service) your **metrics** and key performance indicator (**KPIs**) will be different.

Regarding software, however I can tell you that the vast majority of engagements is in practice managed using **spreadsheet** (like MS excel).

## Service Management

In this case ITIL is often considered a reference framework. The main indicator are defined in the [Service Level Agreements](http://www.sla-zone.co.uk) (**SLAs**) and [Operation Level Agreement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_Level_Agreement) (**OLAs**).

Usually Service engagement will rely on **workflow management** or in IT **[issue management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Issue_tracking_system)** tools (like Jira or [others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_issue_tracking_systems)).

## Project Management

Often in non agile IT projects [Earned Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earned_value) is used to provide indication about the progress.
Scrum methodology comes with its own set of metrics usually mixed with custom indicator relevant to the engagement.

In term of software, **Source code repositories** (like TFS or [others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_revision_control_software)) provide very relevant data but dedicated **project planning tools** (like MS project or [others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_project_management_software)) are often used.

## In all cases

You will need to identify the stakeholders of your engagement. Take the time to discuss with them what is important for them to monitor and define custom indicators as needed.